# Typings for sub-folders inside a root index.d.ts

Tags: typescript, material-ui, definitelytyped

We created typings for `material-ui@next` and want to ship them with the library, which we did with the last beta.

Here is a link to the [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/512ebee03a90980997c7833b71ac09a662609c9c/typings/index.d.ts).

But the typings are not usable in their current form. In development they where used locally and worked fine, but when shipping the files with the library TypeScript seems to use a different discovery strategy.

All typings that reference a subfolder (e.g. `declare 'material-ui/Button/Button'`) will not be found be TypeScript. When importing components an error will show up:

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'material-ui/Button/Button'. '<project path>/node_modules/material-ui/Button/Button.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/material-ui/Button/Button` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'material-ui/Button/Button';`
```

Does TypeScript not accept declaring other imports when used inside the `npm_modules` folder? Because as said, using them locally or even moving them to `@types/material-ui` will make them work.

Also, TypeScript seems to find the `index.d.ts`, because importing from the "root" works (`import { Button} from 'material-ui'`).

Comment: Typescript automatically searches for types in `@types` and, I believe, node packages with a `typings` key in the `package.json`. Do you have anything pointing to `index.d.ts` in your package manifest or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, TS also find the typings. Importing like `{ Button } from ' material-ui'` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, turns out that TypeScript treats typings inside of `node_modules/@types/*` and `node_modules/*` slightly different:

Typings in **`@types`** are so called augmented modules. They are global and everything in them will be on your project's code. This is why accessing submodule declarations, like `material-ui/Button/Button`, work.

Regular npm modules are treated as (regular) modules. Thus, if you import a subfolder the subfolder must contain typings. TypeScript will not go to the root of the modules and check if the typings there have augmented modules.

This means that you (a) have to publish your typings to `DefinitelyTyped` or created `.d.ts` files for every subfolder and file.

You can find a longer explanation here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17945

Comment: really wish that would be more documented. Usually a developer fiddle with typings when it has to troubleshoot, lack of documentation in this surrounding can led to typescript dismissal

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating this a bit; it's quite confusing.

As far as I can tell, an `index.d.ts` with definitions in submodules will work *if there is any reference to the file anywhere in the project* and it does not contain module-less declarations.

For example, this works:

```
// node_modules/b/index.d.ts
declare module 'b/sub' {
  export function boo(): void;
}

declare module 'b' {
  export function bla(): void;
}

// index.ts
import { boo } from 'b/sub';

boo();

// xedni.ts
import { bla } from 'b';

bla();
```

However, delete `xedni.ts` and the import in `index.ts` will stop working.

Adding `/// <reference types="b" />` to `index.ts` or setting `types: ["b"]` in the `tsconfig.json` will make it work again.

Add `export function bah(): void;` to `index.d.ts` and there seems to be no way to get it to work.

I find the behavior quite unintuitive...